# Term for the feeling after having found out the mundane truth behind something

Tags: phrase-request

It's on the tip of my tongue, but doesn't want to bubble to the surface.  I thought you people might be able to help me recall this word.  It would apply in the following examples to fill in the blanks:

> After believing for years that the strange structure was created by
>   alien lifeforms, finding out the simple, Earthly explanation left Beth
>   feeling [blank].

.

> The boy left the show [blank] after sneaking to the side of the stage
>   and seeing the secrets of the magician's tricks.

Disenchanted and demystified, which aren't the correct terms, are popping into my head.  Perhaps they suggest that the correct word is similar.

Answer (score 3):

Moments after I posted, I finally remembered: DISILLUSIONED.

Comment: I like that you remembered "disillusioned" after literally posting an example of a boy finding out the truth behind magical *illusions* :)

Comment: @Sarah - Yes and I was literally picturing scenes from the movie The Illusionist.

Comment: Is it that that you're talking to yourself, once you _did_ remember the word? Is there any other way we could help? I wish I could, I swear.

Comment: @Rompey It's OK for folks to answer their own questions. http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @ColleenV Oh is that what he was talking about? I couldn't make sense of it so I just let it go.

Answer (score 1):

"Disenchanted" is another word to describe the feeling of being disillusioned, the common synonym of the both being *disappointed*, which has the synonyms of its own, as well.

Comment: Indeed. I mentioned disenchanted but it wasn't quite right for the usage I was after.  I would say disillusioned and disenchanted can sometimes be used interchangeably, but the subtle differences (can) have to do with losing fervor (enchantment) versus losing ignorance of the truth (illusion).